# curl php как настроить параметры порт :8443

Tags: php, curl

Здраствуйте ребята. Вопрос такой,  как настроить параметры порт :8443

```
$url_xbtce_BTCUSD = 'https://cryptottlivewebapi.xbtce.net:8443/api/v1/public/ticker/btcusd';
$xbtce = curl_init($url_xbtce_BTCUSD);
curl_setopt($xbtce, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,true);
curl_setopt($xbtce, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($xbtce, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$xbtce_String = curl_exec($xbtce);
curl_close($xbtce);
echo $xbtce_String;
```

Comment: что именно вы хотите настроить? вы и так обращаетесь к 8443 порту в url

Comment: curl_setopt($xbtce, CURLOPT_PORT, 8443);